# React/Redux/Redux-saga rendering only the last API value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

I am new to react redux toolkit and redux-saga and have encountered an error where it only renders the last api call value from moviedb api. Also when I console log the state from useSelector, it renders multiple values. Here's my code

> App.js
>
> ```js
> import "./App.css";
> import Row from "./components/Row";
> import requests from "./requests";
>
> function App() {
>   return (
>     <div className="App">
>       <Row
>         title="Netflix Originals"
>         fetchUrl={requests.fetchNetflixOriginals}
>       />
>       <Row title="Trending Now" fetchUrl={requests.fetchTrending} />
>       {/* <Row title="Top Rated" fetchUrl={requests.fetchTopRated} />
>       <Row title="Action Movies" fetchUrl={requests.fetchActionMovies} />
>       <Row title="Horror Movies" fetchUrl={requests.fetchHorrorMovies} /> */}
>     </div>
>   );
> }
>
> export default App;
> ```

> Store.js

```js
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import { watcherSaga } from "./sagas/rootSaga";
import movieReducer from "./ducks/movieSlice";

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const reducer = combineReducers({
  movie: movieReducer,
});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer,
  middleware: [sagaMiddleware],
});

sagaMiddleware.run(watcherSaga);

export default store;
```

> movieSlice.js

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const movieSlice = createSlice({
  name: "movie",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    getMovie() {},
    setMovie(state, action) {
      const movieData = action.payload;
      return { ...state, ...movieData };
    },
  },
});

export const { getMovie, setMovie } = movieSlice.actions;

export default movieSlice.reducer;
```

> rootSaga.js

```js
import { takeEvery, takeLatest } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { getMovie } from "../ducks/movieSlice";
import { handleGetMovie } from "./handlers/movies";

export function* watcherSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(getMovie.type, handleGetMovie);
}
```

handler

> movie.js

```js
import { call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { requestGetMovie } from "../requests/movies";
import { setMovie } from "../../ducks/movieSlice";

export function* handleGetMovie(action) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(requestGetMovie, action.payload);
    const { data } = response;
    yield put(setMovie(data));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

requests

> movie.js

```js
import axios from "axios";

const baseURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3";

export function requestGetMovie(url) {
  const URL = baseURL + url.fetchLink;
  return axios.request({
    method: "get",
    url: URL,
  });
}
```

requests.js

```js
const APIKEY = "9cf4e09bc69e9849477a8ac79d29a205";

const requests = {
  fetchTrending: `/trending/all/week?api_key=${APIKEY}&language=en=us`,
  fetchNetflixOriginals: `/discover/tv?api_key=${APIKEY}&with_networks=213`,
  fetchTopRated: `/movie/top_rated?api_key=${APIKEY}&language=en=us`,
  fetchActionMovies: `/discover/movie?api_key=${APIKEY}&with_generes=28`,
  fetchHorrorMovies: `/discover/movie?api_key=${APIKEY}&with_genres=27
    `,
};

export default requests;
```

Row.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getMovie } from "../redux/ducks/movieSlice";

function Row({ title, fetchUrl }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(
      getMovie({
        fetchLink: fetchUrl,
      })
    );
  }, [dispatch, fetchUrl]);
  const movie = useSelector((state) => {
    return state.movie.results;
  });
  console.log(movie);

  return (
    <RowContainer>
      {title}
      <CardsContainer>{movie && movie[0].name}</CardsContainer>
    </RowContainer>
  );
}

export default Row;

const RowContainer = styled.div`
  color: white;
`;

const CardsContainer = styled.div`
  color: white;
`;
```

Netflix orginals should display Lucifer while it renders Money Heist from the latest state value and also if i console.log the movie value, multiple values are repeated even if i have only two row component on app.js. If i have Row component on app.js 5 times, it displays the value 25 times on console.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN87N.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5zFx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies on the file `movieSlice.js`, exactly ​here:

```
setMovie(state, action) {
 ​const movieData = action.payload;
 ​return { ...state, ...movieData };
}
```

You are overriding the movie object everytime you call the `setMovie` action.

What you should do insted is to have separate actions for different movie types like this:

```
const movieSlice = createSlice({
  name: "movie",
  initialState: {
    trendingMovies: [],
    actionMovies: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    setTrendingMovies(state, action) {
      state.trendingMovies = action.payload;
    },
    setActionMovies(state, action) {
      state.actionMovies = action.payload;
    }
  },
});
```